# Python pandas - Is it a bad practice to work with integers as column names?

Tags: python, pandas

The following code leads to an exception by `pandas` `merge` function.

```
first = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AntoineGautier/Data/master/first.txt', header=None)
secnd = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AntoineGautier/Data/master/secnd.txt', header=None)
common_cols = [c for c in first.columns if c in secnd.columns]
first.merge(secnd, on=common_cols, how='left', indicator=True)
```

The following does not.

```
first.columns = first.columns.astype('str')
secnd.columns = secnd.columns.astype('str')
common_cols = [c for c in first.columns if c in secnd.columns]
first.merge(secnd, on=common_cols, how='left', indicator=True)
```

So is it considered a bad practice to work with column names of type `numpy.int64`?

Comment: Already filed as a bug, see [BUG: merging with non-stringlike columns can raise #17962](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17962)

Comment: I see Jeff has his own Guido-like time machine. ;-)